# How to display group_concat() column in datatable as in one column?

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax, datatables

I'm displaying tables by datatables. So i have a `group_concat()` column in my table from database which consists of more than one image files. I want to display it in `datatable` as single column. when i am giving normal syntax it doesn't work. Someone help?

I'm getting like this

[image: What im getting]

But i want somthing like this with all the multiple image in pictures column

[image: Desired]

This is the scripting code i have given for displaying datatable

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#dis').dataTable( {
        "lengthMenu": [[2,5,8,10, 25, 50, -1], [2,5,8,10, 25, 50, "All"]]

    } );
    } );
</script>
```

This is the mysql query for gettiing table:

```
<?php
$conn =mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "project");

$sql="SELECT product.*,images.*, group_concat(images.image) as imag FROM product INNER JOIN images on product.ppid=images.pid group by product.ppid";
?>
```

This is the table detailss:

```
<table id="dis" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>  
<th>ID</th>  
<th>Name</th>
<th>Product Description</th>  
<th>Category</th>  
<th>Subcategory</th>
<th>Images</th>
<th>Edit</th>
</tr>  
</thead>
<?php

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    foreach($result as $row)
{
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['ppid'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['pname'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['prodes'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['cat'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['sucat'];?></td>

<?php
foreach(explode(',',$row['imag']) as $url)
 {?>

   <td>
    <?php  $imageURL = 'pictures/'.$url;?>
   <img src="<?php echo $imageURL; ?>" alt="" width="100" height="100" /><br>
      <?php $t= $row['id'];?>
    <a href="dele.php?id=<?php echo $t ; ?>">Delete </a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
</td>
```

I have included all the scripting , css links.... so how i can get this as a datable

Comment: please can u show what output u get  and what output u desired

Comment: I have edited the question... i added the pictures of output as u said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this :
in your code you are repeating `<td>` in `foreach` loop.

you have to place `<td>` tag outside foreach loop

```
<td>  
    <?php
    $img_arr = explode(',',$row['imag']);
    if(!empty($img_arr)){
        foreach($img_arr as $url)
        {  
            $imageURL = 'pictures/'.$url;
            $t= $row['id'];?>
            <img src="<?php echo $imageURL; ?>" alt="" width="100" height="100" /><br>
            <a href="dele.php?id=<?php echo $t ; ?>">Delete </a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <?php 
        }   
    }
    ?>
</td>
```

Comment: thankss... i already solved...i noted that problem how i put td... afterthat i got right answer...thanks anyway :))))))